# Variable prints fine in Vim but not in Bash, how can this happen?

Tags: linux, bash, vim

I was following some resources on Vim defaults and I found that there is a defaults file in `$VIMRUNTIME/defaults.vim` so I tried to print the `$VIMRUNTIME` variable.

1. I tried in Vim using the command `!`, I used `!echo $VIMRUNTIME` and it printed a path
2. I tried in a normal terminal using `echo $VIMRUNTIME` but it prints an empty line

I thought `!` just invokes the command in the terminal but there is a difference in output.

How is this happening? I am a newbie to Linux so maybe I am missing something.

My only guess was that this variable is set when Vim is running but then I tried to execute that command in a terminal when Vim was running, but still got an empty line in the terminal.

Comment: The variable is set in the environment where vim is running. If the terminal was run from vim, then it might have the variable set, otherwise it's empty.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You're missing the notion of an *environment*. As the name implies, *environment variables* reside in an environment. They can be inherited from parent to child but not vice versa.
You may be familiar with concepts like this from your favorite programming language.

In your concrete example, Vim creates `VIMRUNTIME` (according to `:help VIMRUNTIME`) and inherits it to its child processes. That's why it's visible in commands like `:!`, `:sh` or `:terminal`.

It's not visible in unrelated terminals. That's a good thing. Imagine you want to try something out and set e.g. `VIMRUNTIME` to some funky value. You don't want your existing Vim sessions to pick it up and start to misbehave.

Back to your original problem: to find out from where Vim loads what, the `:scriptnames` command may come in handy. The aforementioned `:help VIMRUNTIME` also features a code snippet to access `VIMRUNTIME` from the shell.

Comment: thank you for your answer and the surrounding context, as a Linux beginner this is helpful.

Comment: As a Linux beginner, you should probably stay away from Vim for a while.

Comment: @romainl that would make it awfully hard to complete step 3 of an arbitrary Linux tutorial: `sudo vim /etc/some_file`...

Comment: To be precise, the environment is not related to the programming language but to the OS process

Comment: @DiegoTorresMilano thanks for the remark. I didn't mean it that way but it could easily be read that way. I edited and hope I made my analogy more clear.